# Aliasing names of polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to implement a polymorphic association in a project for the first time but I'm not a fan of how the associations read and was wondering if there's a way of aliasing them?

Example:

```
# app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

# app/models/picture.rb
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

Let's say I wanted to retrieve a Post instance from a given Comment, `terrific_post = Comment.first.commentable` just doesn't read well in my opinion. Is there a way to alias different association names in the Comment model and avoid relying on a single name such as `commentable`?  I realize you could choose a name which aligns better to your specific dsl rather than say "commentable", however I'd prefer to continue referring to associations with names (or variations) based on their relationships, similar to `Comment.first.post` and `Comment.first.picture' if at all possible.

At the end of the day it's not a big sacrifice for the flexibility you get with polymorphic associations. Just curious if a solution exists.

Note: the following example was taken from [The Odin Project](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/active-record-associations) which does a great job explaining various types of associations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alias an association like any other method:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  alias_method :post, :commentable
  alias_method :picture, :commentable
end
```

And you can then do `Comment.first.post` and `Comment.first.picture`.

But `Comment.first.post` can be either a `Post` or a `Picture`,
so you should know what are you doing.

Another approach would be implement methods that return `post` only if `commentable` is a `Post` and `picture` only when `commentable` is a `Picture`:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true

  def post
    commentable if commentable.is_a? Post
  end

  def picture
    commentable if commentable.is_a? Picture
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Seems to work perfectly.  I've been a little hesitant to go outside of rails when overwriting activerecord methods, been a little hesitant to use anything outside of rails to overwrite activerecord

Comment: *Ugh excuse the gibberish, typing on the go isn't always a great idea. I was trying to ask about overwriting activerecord methods.  In the past I've been warned against it but at least in this situation it seems to work just fine.  Would there be anything to watch out for in taking this approach?

Comment: I have updated the answer to ensure that method `Comment#post` returns only entity of type `Post` or nil, and same for `Comment#picture`. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up packaging my solution into a [gem](https://github.com/mansakondo/polymorphic_aliases) for experimental purposes. Feel free to try it.